# Destructuring a list of lists in elm

Tags: elm

I'm trying to destructure a list of lists in elm (0.18).  Here's the function call:

```
  twoColumns
       [ [ Widget1, Widget2 ]
       , [ Widget3, Widget4 ]
       ]
```

That calls this function:

```
twoColumns : List List Widget -> Html Msg
twoColumns listoflists =
   case listoflists of
      listLeft :: listRight :: _ ->
         div []
             [ div [ class "col-md-6" ] (parsingOperation listLeft)
             , div [ class "col-md-6" ] (parsingOperation listRight)
             ]
      _ ->
         div [] [ text "Error" ]
```

(Let's assume that parseOptions accepts `List Widget` as an argument.)

This seems like straightforward destructuring, but I'm getting this error:

```
Tag `::` is causing problems in this pattern match.

71|             listLeft :: listRight :: _ ->
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The pattern matches things of type:

    List a

But the values it will actually be trying to match are:

    List List Widget
```

Any ideas?

*Note* When I try to use the pattern `(listLeft::listRight::_)`, elm-format reverts it to the pattern above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List List Widget` should be `List (List Widget)` instead. Because `List List Widget` means a totally different (and pretty pointless) thing. However, this is very interesting why Elm compiler even allows `List List Widget`. I guess this is a bug of the compiler.